# Is it a correct form of expression to say that one is impressed upon by stress?

Tags: verbs

I would like to know if it is correct to use the word "impressed" in this way by saying that someone is impressed upon by daily pressure? Not in the sense of to be convinced but to be negatively impacted or affected. I was trying to be more explicit in emphasizing a greater degree of being affected. Or perhaps beleaguered or beset would have been better?

I tried to verify this by looking at the dictionary and it is defined tr.v. 1. To affect strongly, often favorably 2. To produce or attempt to produce a vivid impression or image of: a scene that impressed itself on her memory 3. To mark or stamp with pressure: impressed the wax with a design. 4. To apply with pressure; press: impressed the stamp onto the wax.

I am not sure.

Comment: No, such use of *impressed* is not idiomatic (it's usually used in a positive sense, to mean *[caused to] have a favourable impression of*). What you're trying to say would be expressed by, for example, ***weighed down** by daily pressure* (or perhaps ***oppressed***).

Comment: Seeing the definition **impress: affect strongly** in a dictionary may create the impression (oops) that it is acceptable to use 'impress' interchangeably with 'affect strongly'. This is far from the truth. 'His callousness affected me strongly' works, but hardly 'his callousness impressed me'. 'The strong wind strongly affected the boat's steering' but not 'the strong wind impressed the boat's steering'. Dictionary definitions are just a start in deciding acceptability. And in your case, the answer is that 'impressed upon' is unacceptable. Oh, and hello, Gaia :)

Comment: Agree with both remarks, and I would add here that the minimal semantic trait of impress is to make a mark on. Generally, then, stress does  not "make a mark" on the psyche. It is either present or not as a sort of totality. A person can be impressed by a quality another person or thing has but like a physical mark, it affects some part of the person not the totality of the psyche like stress. So, /his precision impresses me/ [makes it "mark" on my mind] but it is not taking over my mind as a total state of being. Other verbs: overcome by stress, for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How about: *The seriousness of the situation in which the surviving passengers found themselves, slowly impressed itself upon them*? That sounds idiomatic enough to me.

Comment: @WS2: That sounds fine to me too. But without the guidance of reflexive ***itself*** plus ***upon***, you must admit *The seriousness of the situation slowly impressed the surviving passengers* would be rather "unusual" phrasing (and would probably be taken to mean something rather different).

Comment: @FumbleFingers See my answer - especially the more recent OED examples from Dickens and Eliot. *The seriousness of the situation was slowly impressed on the survivors*

Comment: @WS2 (1) But OP doesn't want the 'convince [of the seriousness of the situation]' sense; (2) 'They were impressed [upon] by the stress of the situation' cannot be used for  'They were strongly affected by the stress of the situation'. There are 4 Indian / Ghanaian English usages found in a Google search for "they were impressed upon by".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I hear what you say. But if one can use *The seriousness was gradually impressed on the participants*; it doesn't seem to me a gigantic leap to *The stress of what was going on in the Leppings Lane End was starting to impress itself on the officials running the match*. Seems what we are talking about is the difference between the *seriousness impressing itself on...*, and *the seriousness impressing...*. Problem is the alternative sense of *being impressed* gets in the way of extending the usage. But this discussion may be helpful to the OP.

Comment: It seems a gigantic leap to me. From England to (a few small spots in) India. ELU is about how English is used, not about what might logically be expected of it.

Answer (score -1):

**The answer is *yes*, it can be used in just that way. It is sense 3 of the *v1* use of impress in the OED. It is a figurative use of the physical sense of making an impression, and not the same as mentally acquiring a favourable view of something**

> 3. fig. To imprint (an idea, etc.) on (†in, to) the mind; to cause to take firm mental hold; to enforce, urge (a rule of conduct, etc.) on
>      another.
>
> c1374   Chaucer Troilus & Criseyde ii. 1322 (1371)   Yn good herte it
>   mot som rouþe impresse, To here and se þe giltless in distresse.
>
> c1400   Mandeville's Trav. (1839) xxix. 295   Thou scholdest thenke
>   and impresse it in thi mynde, that nothing is inmortalle.
>
> ▸?a1513   W. Dunbar Poems (1998) 121   Sadlye in thy hart inpres Quod
>   tu in cinerem reuerteris.
>
> 1590   Spenser Faerie Queene ii. xi. sig. Y7v,   So fowle and vgly,
>   that exceeding feare Their visages imprest, when they approached
>   neare.
>
> 1590   Spenser Faerie Queene iii. iv. sig. Ff6v,   So deepe the deadly
>   feare of that foule swaine Was earst impressed in her gentle spright.
>
> 1649   J. Ellistone tr. J. Böhme Epist. i. xxxix. 9   That a man
>   impresseth (or imagineth in his minde) to himselfe, that Christ is
>   dead for his sinnes.
>
> a1711   T. Ken Divine Love in Wks. (1838) 238   Impress on my heart so
>   tender a sense of thy sufferings.
>
> 1776   Gibbon Decline & Fall I. xi. 297   A few such examples
>   impressed a salutary consternation.
>
> 1839   Dickens Nicholas Nickleby x. 90,   I am sure you will impress
>   upon your children the necessity of attaching themselves to it early
>   in life.
>
> 1863   ‘G. Eliot’ Romola II. i. 6   This man had a power..of
>   impressing his beliefs on others.